# Accessing the NSArray values of the NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am working on bringing a url into a table view using MWFeedParser.  I have read the documentation and discovered that I can access the item.enclosures (NSArray of NSDictionary with keys url, type and length).  I would like to access the URL out of the array.  I need help figuring out how to access the NSArray values of the NSDictionary and this is what I have so far.

```
if (indexPath.section == SectionHeader && indexPath.row == SectionHeaderEnclosure) {
    if (item.enclosures) {
        for (NSDictionary *url in item.enclosures){
            //How to access here;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (indexPath.section == SectionHeader && indexPath.row == SectionHeaderEnclosure) {  
    if (item.enclosures) {  
        for (NSDictionary *dict in item.enclosures){  
            NSString *url = [dict objectForKey:@"url"];  
            NSLog(@" url is : %@",url);  
        }  
    }  
}
```